# Calculating Shortest Distance between two GameObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two GameObjects. One VERY big, one VERY small. Think of a runway and a small plane on it. I try to determine the distance between those two objects using Vector3:

```
var distance=Vector3.Distance(runway.transform.position, plane.transform.position);
```

Now when the plane is in the middle of the runway I receive a very small value for distance (like 0.5). But at the end of the runway I receive quite high values. IMHO this is because I compare the *center* of both GameObjects and not the *closest* distance.

Is there a way to get the closest distance between those two?

(the "runway" is not in a flat angle so I can *not* just compare the Y-axis for this)

Comment: Possibility look into these two: [Bounds.Intersects](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Intersects.html) and [Bounds.ClosestPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.ClosestPoint.html).

Comment: yes you could get your object's bounds, either from the collider, or the renderer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "runway" has a collider attached to it, you can use something like ClosestPointOnBounds(Vector3 position), which returns the point on the collider bounds that is closest to "position". So something like this could work:

```
Collider col = GetComponent<Collider>();
Vector3 closestPoint = col.ClosestPointOnBounds(planePosition);
```

Can read more about this here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds.html