# Call InvokeRepeating in Update Method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to program an AI Tank. I want it to fire every so often. I use the invokeRepeating method in the start method that will fire a projectile every so often. The problem is that I need it to only fire when certain "rules" are meant. I need to find the distance between 2 gameObjects. How do I do that? Once I understand how to do that I need to place it in the update method. This is because it needs to do the check for distance every frame and only in update can I check if something occurs every so often. So what I need is two things :

1. How to find the distance between 2 gameObjects and store that value as a float.
2. How to use the float value and check if it is within a certain radius and if so call the InvokeRepeating method.

If I am not being clear enough, please ask. I will try my best to clarify.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating Shortest Distance between two GameObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617524/calculating-shortest-distance-between-two-gameobjects)

Comment: Not exactly, I used Vector3.Distance for calculating the distance.

Comment: That's the distance between the centers of two objects ;) Not what you asked in the question

Comment: Hi, I don't see how large of a difference it would make in my game. Wouldn't that only change the values by a bit?

Comment: depends on how big your tanks are and if they only need to get as close as the closest part

Comment: What do you mean by "to get as close as the closest part"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update method is for running repeatedly. Using InvokeRepeating in the update method would be like an update within an update method. InvokeRepeating should always be in the Start or Awake methods.

```
// Find player in range and fire projectiles
public GameObject player;
 public GameObject tank;
float range = 100f;

void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("Shoot", 0.1f, 0.25f);
}

void Shoot()
{
    if (player != null && tank != null)
    {
        float dist = Vector3.Distance(tank.transform.position, player.transform.position);
        if (dist <= range)
        {
            FireProjectile();
        }
    }
    else
    {
Debug.Log("Game object(s) is/are null.");
    }
}

void FireProjectile()
{
    // Code to shoot projectiles
}
```

I'm sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think the issue here is that OP didn't describe the goal clear enough and didn't post any code. Your answer and code example is fine however it will probably not really be helpful since we don't know exactly what OP is trying to achieve here ;)

Comment: Actually, it was really helpful. It solved my problem. I only had to change the Vector3 dist to float dist and it worked. I essentially copied  your code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for notifying me the mistake. I changed it to float.