# How to get shortest distance between two objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]I have two objects with a significant size difference. I want to find the shortest possible distance between those objects. For example, if I have a small chair in front of a wall. I want the distance between the chair and the wall. I tried using Vector3.distance, but it calculates using world coordinates. I tried using colliders to achieve this as I had read somewhere that it was the solution but was unclear on how to go about it. Can someone please help?

I have added an image to illustrate what I want. The red line is the distance I get when I use Vector3.Distance, however the distance I want is the green line. If there are many objects in the game, how can I get the shortest distance between the two objects I have selected.

Comment: Would this answer your question: [Calculating Shortest Distance between two GameObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617524/calculating-shortest-distance-between-two-gameobjects) ?

Comment: for the distance between the two object pivots or centres [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html). You might also fing useful [Collider.ClosestPonit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPoint.html) and [Collider.ColsestPointOnBounds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPointOnBounds.html). For other particular "shortest distance" you might need to explain better what you want and probably code that out yourself.

Comment: @derHugo I checked that out but it is specific to two objects. I want it to be more universal, if that makes sense.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I tried closestpointsonbounds but I did not understand how to implement it. If it is possible, can I find the distance between two objects along one axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can use [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ProjectOnPlane.html), you need to pass `yourObject` position as the first param and `wall.up` as the second param (in case your wall transform up pointing to the `yourObject` side). Then you will receive a point on the wall projected on the wall perpendicularly to the wall. Get this point and use `Vector3.Distance` from the `yourObject` position to the projected point.

```
var pointOnWall = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(yourObject.position, wall.up);
var closestDistance = Vector3.Distance(yourObject.position, pointOnWall);
```

Comment: This gives me distance between the object and the world origin for some reason

Comment: It still seems to give me the distance between the center of the wall and the object. I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Please replace with this code calucation of poitnOnWall: var pointOnWall = wall.TransformPoint(Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(yourObject.position, wall.up)); Transform.TransformPoint transforming position from a local position to a world position. ProjectOnPlane returns local position on the wall. Sorry for the missleading.

Comment: @s-h-s https://pastebin.com/3WbzWmUg attach this to the cube and in the scene view, you will see the result of the calculation. Set `closeDistance` more than the size of cude.